# Change the font of brackets in the math mode for mtpro2

Tags: fonts, mtpro

I have installed the mtpro2 package. I want to set the font of brackets in the math mode the same as that in the text mode. See the code below:

```
% compile with pdflatex using mac
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{mtpro2}
\begin{document}

$[x_n\to x\text{ in }\sigma(E,E^*)]$

[$x_n\to x\text{ in }\sigma(E,E^*)$]

\end{document}
```

[image]
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine the brackets in normal size to be taken from the `operators` math font (that points to the main text font).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\DeclareMathDelimiter{[}{\mathopen} {operators}{`[}{largesymbols}{"02}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{]}{\mathclose}{operators}{`]}{largesymbols}{"03}


\begin{document}

$[x_n\to x\text{ in }\sigma(E,E^*)]$

[$x_n\to x\text{ in }\sigma(E,E^*)$]

$[\bigl[\Bigl[$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I found the original declaration is `\DeclareMathDelimiter{[}{\mathopen} {operators}{"5B}{largesymbols}{"02}`, so what's the difference between `"5B` and `\`[`? @egreg

Comment: @Stephen I didn't want to go and check the ASCII code for the brackets. ;-)

Comment: OK, I see. By the way, if I delete the `\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}` line in your code (i.e., to use cm math font), then the fonts of brackets in two cases are different. Why this happens?

Comment: @Stephen Please, don't mix Times for text and CM for math: the combination is horrible. The `newtxtext` package doesn't set the `operators` font, so it remains CM.

Comment: Actually this is just my code test. When I need to write some formal documents, I always keep the text font and math font consistent.